# how to create API App in Azure using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-api-apps

I am trying to create an API App in Azure App Service using Terraform but could not get anything to do so.
Even I could not find anything in AZ CLI to create an API app.

Is there any work-around to do the same using terraform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to create Azure API App from Terraform at the moment.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/443

There is workaround how to create Azure API App with AZ CLI

```
az resource create -g yugangw2 -n yugangw2-api12 --resource-type Microsoft.web/sites  --is-full-object -p "{\"kind\":\"api\", \"location\":\"West US\", \"properties\":{  \"serverFarmId\":\"/subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-cb9272xxxxxx/resourcegroups/yugangw2/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/yugangw2-plan\"}}"
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/2866#issuecomment-317544291

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays (in late 2021) it seems there is no **real** difference between **App Service** and **API Service** (different icons).

So you could just use [azurerm_app_service](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service) for both API and Web Apps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to provision API APP using "kind" attribute in the template. set the kind attribute to "API".
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app
kind - The Kind value for this Windows Web App.

Example:
"kind": "linux,container,API"