# Can I create an API app in Azure using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74737903/438323) one should be able to add the *"kind"* attribute and set its value to *"api"* in the [azurerm_windows_web_app](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_web_app) resource, but when I do this I get this error:

> Can't configure a value for "kind": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

Is there a way to accomplish this in another way using Terraform? I want the resource to specifically be an API app (with the special icon) in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't configure a value for "kind": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

The `Kind` parameter works with the old `azurerm_app_service_plan` module but not with the new `azurerm_service_plan` module. I also encountered the same error when using the new module.

[image]

Alternatively, you can create a web app with the `Kind` parameter using the old `azurerm_app_service_plan` module in `Terraform`

Below are the values supported in the `Kind` operation.

> Note: `'Kind: API'` is not supported in the old module either.

[image]

```json
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "webapp-rg-2"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "webapp-appserviceplan"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      kind                = "App"
      reserved            = true
      sku {
        tier = "Standard"
        size = "S1"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "example" {
      name                = "windows-webapp-test1"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
     
     site_config {}
    }
```

**Terraform Plan**
[image]

**Terraform Apply**

[image]

Once the `Terraform` code is run, the web app has been created.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so then it seems I'm out of luck creating an API app using Terraform. As I understand there isn't much difference except the name and logo between an api app and a web app. So guess I need to check if we can live with the "wrong" logo/name.